# How to select parent if a child do not have attribute & if another attribute is empty

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<table>
<select>
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option selected="selected" value></option>
<select>
<select>
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option selected="selected" value></option>
<select>

<select>
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option selected="selected" value></option>
<select>

<select>
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option selected="selected" value></option>
<select>
</table>
```

How can I select all nodes except the **second one** which has two `selected` attributes using XPath? Things I have tried:

`*//table//[select[not(@value='') and not(option[@selected='selected'])]]`

But the above selects all four `select` or dropdown nodes, how to select all nodes except the second one?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting all `select` nodes that don't contain more than one `option` node with a `selected` attribute:

```
//table/select[ count( option[ @selected ] ) < 2 ]
```

```xml
<select>
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option selected="selected" value=""/>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option selected="selected" value=""/>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option selected="selected" value=""/>
</select>
```